# Using multiple facebook FriendPickerFragments in the same activity

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments

I've come across a problem where I cannot display the list of friends in a FriendPickerFragment if I have another FriendPickerFragment in the fragment backstack.

The first FriendPickerFragment loads a friend list but when I replaces it with a new instance of a FriendPickerFragment the new one does not display any data.

Is there anyone who have come across this and know a solution/workaround?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

When you use the FragmentManager to add a fragment to a layout from the code the id must be unique in the whole stack of fragments.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.MUST_BE_UNIQUE_IN_STACK, mPickerFragment)
    .commit();
```